# Calculating fundamental groups using retracts

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups

I want to know if my calculations are correct. I am trying to find the fundamental group of the figure $X_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained by drawing $n$ lines between two points (the lines only meet at those two points).

First two cases are trivial and I found that for $n=3$, using Seifert-Van Kampen's theorem, is$$\pi_1(X_3)=Z\langle a_1,a_2\rangle$$
so my guess would be that
$$\pi_1(X_n)=Z\langle a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}\rangle$$
is this correct? and if so, would induction work?. I don't manage to do it that way.

Comment: This space is homotopy equivalent to wedge of $n-1$ circles (slide the who figure along one of the lines joining the two points). So by SvKT and induction, $\pi_1 \cong F_{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I don't know how I didn't see that earlier, question looks dumb now.